# Can't figure out what's wrong with SQL syntax

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (t=null) then update employee set grade='x' where empid=id; END' at line 4

I am not able to understand where the syntax is wrong.

I am creating a procedure to get a grade from the table if it grade is present. If it is not present then it should be updated as x.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGETgrade (in id int)
BEGIN
select grade as t from employee where empid=id
if (t=null) then
update employee set grade='x' where empid=id;
END $$
```

Comment: could you please provide info on what error you are getting?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (t=null) then
update employee set grade='x' where empid=id;`
END' at line 4

Comment: I think you need to use `IS NULL`: `if (t IS NULL) then` ...

Comment: @jarekJozwik it is not working

Comment: Missing `;`? after select

Comment: Next time, put the error in your question immediately. Questions shouldn't be posted without full info needed to discuss them, and _'I don't understand this error I'm not showing you'_ is not a usable problem description. And essential info like that shouldn't be left in comments, which can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need "**;**" after the first query

```
select grade as t from employee where empid=id; <<---
```

and

```
IF THEN
     ...
END IF; <<--
```